# What is the meaning of word 'crack' in chapter 33 of A Game of Thrones?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire, terminology

From chapter 33 of *A Game of Thrones*:

> "It's not murder I find amusing, Lord Stark, it's you. You rule like a man dancing on rotten ice. I daresay you will make a noble splash. I believe I heard the first crack this morning." said by Lord Baelish.
>
> "The first and last," said Ned. "I've had my fill."

What is the meaning of 'crack'? And what's "I have had my fill"? What are they talking about?

Comment: This is an interesting question because it highlights the things in our environment that we take for granted. As someone that grew up in a temperate climate and seen frozen ponds/For regularly, there is no ambiguity about wh/coldat cracking of rotten ice is. But at the same time, I can totally see how a huge portion of the world's population would not make that correlation, not having had the same experiences with cold weather. Makes me wonder how many things that others take for granted wouldn't make sense to me. Very nice question.

Comment: Retracted my close vote because of a meta discussion where Rand al'Thor basically approved questions like this. Can't find the link, though!

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath [This one](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11626/58193) - and yes this is on topic but people will always insist on closing them.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot out of curiosity, wouldn't this question be a better fit for EL or EL&U? (btw I don't usually participate here, I just like reading the Q&As)

Comment: @Dzyann - that would only help understand the passage semantically, not how *it relates to the plot* (<on topic) and would leave exactly "what they're talking about" up to a language enthusiast instead of a SciFi guru.

Comment: @Dzyann On top of what Mazyra has said. This fits both sites perfectly fine, there is some overlap. Similar to how we overlap with M&TV. Just because it is on topic on one site doesn’t make it off topic on another and in this specific case they wouldn’t have gotten Aegon’s excellent answer had it been posted there.

Comment: @Dzyann for EL, perhaps, yes. But it would be unwelcome and off topic in ELU since it deals with two very common English idioms.

Comment: I think this is more a question for https://ell.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @Mazura Which is exactly what is being asked. The question does not ask for plot relevance, only the meaning of the statements. I can answer the question asked with absolutely no knowledge of the story in question. That is why people want it moved to a different place, where experts on language would be better able to explain at the level of the speaker.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot The question, as currently asked, only asks about the meaning of words and English idiom. The exact same question could be asked even if the story were not about a fantasy work at all. The user would get a better answer on a subreddit devoted to explaining English idioms. Instead, we have people here with SF knowledge trying to handle explaining the English language while using English, and then adding a bunch of extra information that was not asked. It's suboptimal at best.

Comment: @trlkly It is on topic here so there is no point moving it, and it would be somewhat harmful to move it. Just because the question can be asked perfectly well elsewhere doesn't mean it should be moved. The extra information "that was not asked" is actually extremely helpful in working out the context of what was said and _why_. I'm not sure the user _would_ get a better answer, they might do but they might also get an even better one here. _"It's suboptimal at best"_ - I very much object to this last statement too. If you want to challenge the on topicness though you should take it to meta.

Comment: @trlkly I believe I will chime in. There's nothing, in my opinion, in OP's question that indicates he wants semantical meaning w.r.t English language. **I believe a lot of people are simply assuming that OP asked for that only because he's from India, not an Anglophone country**. Furthermore OP never indicated that he asked that question about English language at all. For all we know, he may have been asking about relevance to the plot. But of course it is possible that I am missing something here given that I am not a native speaker either. Anyways lets not assume, let OP confirm.

Comment: So since I didn't grow up near a desert, I won't understand analogies about walking through the desert, desert sands etc. Please.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot TBH, I think Aegon's answer here is overkill. The in-story context could have been explained in a paragraph without need for massive quotes, and it seems the OP is asking about the *meaning of the word* rather than its plot significance. (Agreed this is definitely on-topic though.)

Comment: @Randal'Thor oh it’s certainly overkill but my point was it is a good answer that we wouldn’t have gotten on ELL or EL&U.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

> "You rule like a man dancing on rotten ice"

He's taking foolish risks.
"On rotten ice" means melting ice, which will soon crack and break, plunging the "dancer" into freezing water, where he will be swept under the ice to drown.

> "I believe I heard the first crack this morning"

The first crack in the ice, meaning the ice will soon break.

Baelish is saying "Your style of rule is dangerous to you, you are putting yourself in danger, and your action this morning will have repercussions that you will regret".

Essentially he's saying that Ned is [shooting himself in the foot](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/shoot-yourself-in-the-foot).

By "had my fill" Ned is saying he doesn't want to rule anymore. It's a metaphor taken from eating/drinking.
"Would you like some more food?"
You could answer "No thank you, I've had my fill", however "I've had my fill" is generally taken in a negative way, so it wouldn't be a polite thing to say at dinner.

However the following is perfectly acceptable (no one would think you've been eating zombies)

> "Would you like to watch The Walking Dead with me?"
>   "No thanks, I've had my fill of zombies."

Comment: "I've had my fill of *x*" is a more polite way of saying "I'm sick of *x*".

Comment: I like zombies, but I couldn’t eat a whole one.

Comment: _"The first crack in the ice, meaning the ice will soon break"_ That's not really an accurate causal relationship; it would be more accurate to say that the first crack in the ice demonstrates that the ice is crackable and usually suggests further cracks (and eventually breakage) to come.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit His post doesn't state a causal relationship, merely a correlation. When one is walking on "rotten" (thin, melting) ice, the sound of the ice cracking is soon followed by the ice collapsing. The cause for both is the same: the failure of the structural integrity of the ice, which is caused by the load being greater than the current structure and temperature of ice can support.

Comment: Since you are explaining some English idioms, it may also be useful to use the word "extended simile" and to flat out state that the "crack" is not literal, but figurative. The Asker will encounter such usage greatly outside the scope of Science Fiction.

Comment: @trlkly I was thinking it doesn't even necessarily correlate, but I concede I have only limited experience with ice. I will take your word for it. :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: If it was regular Ice over a frozen lake I would agree with you, however "rotten ice", it's old and dirty from having gone through several - partial - thaw/re-freezing cycles. I wouldn't sake on such ice, never mind dance on it.

Answer (score 25):

> "I believe I heard the first crack this morning."

Lord Baelish was referring to the quarrel between King Robert and Eddard Stark on proposed murder of Princess Daenerys Stormborn. Robert wanted her murdered along with her unborn baby to deal with the threat of potential Dothraki invasion to restore Targaryen monarchy. All quotes are from the same chapter.

> **“Robert, I beg of you,” Ned pleaded, “hear what you are saying. You
>   are talking of murdering a child.”**
>
> **“The whore is pregnant!” The king’s fist slammed down** on the council
>   table loud as a thunderclap. “I warned you this would happen, Ned.
>   Back in the barrowlands, I warned you, but you did not care to hear
>   it. Well, you’ll hear it now. **I want them dead, mother and child both,
>   and that fool Viserys as well. Is that plain enough for you? I want
>   them dead.”**
>
> The other councillors were all doing their best to pretend that they
>   were somewhere else. No doubt they were wiser than he was. Eddard
>   Stark had seldom felt quite so alone. “You will dishonor yourself
>   forever if you do this.”
>
> “Then let it be on my head, so long as it is done. I am not so blind
>   that I cannot see the shadow of the axe when it is hanging over my own
>   neck.”
>
> “There is no axe,” Ned told his king. “Only the shadow of a shadow,
>   twenty years removed... if it exists at all.”

Most of his council agreed.

> “This ‘dragonspawn’ is in his mother’s belly,” Ned said. “Even Aegon
>   did no conquering until after he was weaned.”
>
> “Gods! You are stubborn as an aurochs, Stark.” The king looked around
>   the council table. “Have the rest of you mislaid your tongues? Will no
>   one talk sense to this frozen-faced fool?”
>
> **Varys gave the king an unctuous smile** and laid a soft hand on Ned’s
>   sleeve. “I understand your qualms, Lord Eddard, truly I do. It gave me
>   no joy to bring this grievous news to council. It is a terrible thing
>   we contemplate, a vile thing. Yet **we who presume to rule must do vile
>   things for the good of the realm, howevermuch it pains us.**”
>
> **Lord Renly shrugged. “The matter seems simple enough to me. We ought
>   to have had Viserys and his sister killed years ago, but His Grace my
>   brother made the mistake of listening to Jon Arryn.**”
>
> [...]
>
> **Grand Maester Pycelle cleared his throat**, a process that seemed to
>   take some minutes. “My order serves the realm, not the ruler. Once I
>   counseled King Aerys as loyally as I counsel King Robert now, so I
>   bear this girl child of his no ill will. Yet I ask you this-should war
>   come again, how many soldiers will die? How many towns will burn? How
>   many children will be ripped from their mothers to perish on the end
>   of a spear?” He stroked his luxuriant white beard, infinitely sad,
>   infinitely weary. “**Is it not wiser, even kinder, that Daenerys
>   Targaryen should die now so that tens of thousands might live?**”
>
> [...]
>
> **Littlefinger was the last**. As Ned looked to him, Lord Petyr stifled a
>   yawn. “When you find yourself in bed with an ugly woman, the best
>   thing to do is close your eyes and get on with it,” he declared.
>   “Waiting won’t make the maid any prettier. Kiss her and be done with
>   it.” “Kiss her?” Ser Barristan repeated, aghast. **“A steel kiss,” said
>   Littlefinger**.

Eddard and Barristan Selmy on the other hand were of the opinion that it was dishonourable. Robert was enraged and told Eddard to do as he was commanded to do. Ned also made several comments that insulted Robert.

> “Mercy is never a mistake, Lord Renly,” Ned replied. “On the Trident,
>   Ser Barristan here cut down a dozen good men, Robert’s friends and
>   mine. When they brought him to us, grievously wounded and near death,
>   Roose Bolton urged us to cut his throat, but **your brother said, ‘I
>   will not kill a man for loyalty, nor for fighting well**,’ and sent his
>   own maester to tend Ser Barristan’s wounds.” He gave the king a long
>   cool look. **“Would that man were here today.”**
>
> Robert had shame enough to blush. “It was not the same,” he
>   complained. “Ser Barristan was a knight of the Kingsguard.”
>
> “Whereas Daenerys is a fourteen-year-old girl.” Ned knew he was
>   pushing this well past the point of wisdom, yet he could not keep
>   silent. “Robert, I ask you, what did we rise against Aerys Targaryen
>   for, if not to put an end to the murder of children?”
>
> “To put an end to Targaryens!” the king growled.
>
> “**Your Grace, I never knew you to fear Rhaegar.” Ned fought to keep the
>   scorn out of his voice, and failed. “Have the years so unmanned you
>   that you tremble at the shadow of an unborn child?”**
>
> Robert purpled. **“No more, Ned,” he warned, pointing. “Not another
>   word. Have you forgotten who is king here?”**
>
> **“No, Your Grace,” Ned replied. “Have you?”**
>
> [...]
>
> “Mormont craves a royal pardon,” Lord Renly reminded them.
>
> “Desperately,” Varys said, “yet he craves life even more. By now, the
>   princess nears Vaes Dothrak, where it is death to draw a blade. If I
>   told you what the Dothraki would do to the poor man who used one on a
>   khaleesi, none of you would sleep tonight.” He stroked a powdered
>   cheek. “Now, poison... the tears of Lys, let us say. Khal Drogo need
>   never know it was not a natural death.”
>
> Grand Maester Pycelle’s sleepy eyes flicked open. He squinted
>   suspiciously at the eunuch.
>
> **“Poison is a coward’s weapon,” the king complained.**
>
> **Ned had heard enough. “You send hired knives to kill a fourteen
>   year-old girl and still quibble about honor?”** He pushed back his chair
>   and stood. “Do it yourself, Robert. The man who passes the sentence
>   should swing the sword. Look her in the eyes before you kill her. See
>   her tears, hear her last words. You owe her that much at least.”

In the end, Eddard resigned. Robert then threatened to have him killed in anger (He did not mean it).

> **“I will not be part of murder, Robert. Do as you will, but do not ask
>   me to fix my seal to it.”**
>
> For a moment Robert did not seem to understand what Ned was saying.
>   Defiance was not a dish he tasted often. Slowly his face changed as
>   comprehension came. His eyes narrowed and a flush crept up his neck
>   past the velvet collar. He pointed an angry finger at Ned. “You are
>   the King’s Hand, Lord Stark. **You will do as I command you, or I’ll
>   find me a Hand who will.”**
>
> “I wish him every success.” **Ned unfastened the heavy clasp that
>   clutched at the folds of his cloak, the ornate silver hand that was
>   his badge of office**. He laid it on the table in front of the king,
>   saddened by the memory of the man who had pinned it on him, the friend
>   he had loved. **“I thought you a better man than this, Robert. I thought
>   we had made a nobler king.”**
>
> **Robert’s face was purple. “Out, “ he croaked, choking on his rage.
>   “Out, damn you, I’m done with you. What are you waiting for? Go, run
>   back to Winterfell. And make certain I never look on your face again,
>   or I swear, I’ll have your head on a spike!”**

Baelish compared Eddard's policies and behaviour as akin to a man dancing on rotten ice, liable to break. He considered this disagreement between the King and the Hand as the first crack in the ice.

> "The first and last," said Ned. "I've had my fill."

Here, Eddard says he would no longer serve as the Hand. He had had enough of serving as the Hand and he was going home. (Which he never did as Robert reinstated him and made his peace).